# Most elegant way to set "end condition" for an increment / decrement?

Tags: javascript

Lets assume we have a car driving to a destination:

First scenario:

```
destination to: 100px
```

Second scenario:

```
destination to: -50px
```

Pseudo code:

```
var currentValueToAdd;

if (valueToIncrementPosition > 0) {
  if (currentPositionOfCar <= destination) {
    currentValueToAdd = valueToIncrementPosition;
  } else {
    currentValueToAdd = 0;
  }
} else {
  if (currentPositionOfCar >= destination) {
    currentValueToAdd = valueToIncrementPosition;
  }
  else {
    currentValueToAdd = 0;
  } 
}

car.style.position += currentValueToAdd + "px";
```

As you can see, I can increment -n or n and the ending can be below or higher than the current car position. So my condition for the car to stop driving really varies between less than or more than the destination.

**Is there a better way to write the above solution to making the car stop?** Maybe a formula of some sort?

Other idea I had was to use absolute values which doesnt seem right either:

```
Math.abs(currentPositionOfCar) > Math.abs(destination) ? 0 : valueToIncrementPosition;
```

Comment: Having a working example of this would be so enjoyable to work on to improve :)

Comment: Depends on what you call "elegant".

Comment: @Bálint shorter! :)

Comment: Calculate the next position (current + addition) compare that to destination, and if the sum is going to overflow, decrease the addition so that the car will hit the destination.

Comment: Then I suggest you visit the codegolf stackexchange and ask that in the chat. There's no one who can do it shorter

Comment: @Teemu yes so: addition = destination > (current + addition) : addition : 0;

Comment: @Teemu is this what you mean?

Comment: Not quite, `addition = (destination > (current + addition)) ? addition : current + addition - destination;`.

Comment: @Teemu would you prefer the math.min version below or the ternary one?

Comment: Probably not, executing `Math.abs` is a time-consuming operation. You've to test the performance to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currentPositionOfCar = Math.min(currentPositionOfCar + valueToIncrementPosition, Math.abs(destination));
```

Without names like this:

```
a = Math.min(a + b, Math.abs(c));
// Golfed:
 a=(m=Math).min(a+b,m.abs(c)); // Don't use this, this is very hacky
```

This also has the benefit, that it makes the car stop exactly at fhs destination.

If you really want a short one:

```
a += b;
a > Math.abs(c) && a -= b;
// Golfed:
(a+=b)>Math.abs(c)&&a-=b
```

But this doesn't stoo exactly at the destination and works a bit like your original code

Comment: @Teemu "There's no one who can do it shorter than the ppcg guys". I left that part out accidentally

Comment: @Teemu hehe ya I remember he said that :D

Comment: @Bálint nice one! I like your solution.

Comment: Check out Teemus comment. He is right that Math.min is time consuming. You could do: addition = (destination > (current + addition)) ? addition : current + addition - destination;

Comment: @Asperger 1.) This is JavaScript, if you want speed then you chose wrong 2.) If you don't want to execute this 20k+ times a second, then there'll be no problem